# C++ Changing lower-case letters in a string function (again...)

Tags: c++, string, function, pointers

It's me again. Out of all my questions I think this is the dumbest of them all but either due to fatigue or stupidity I need some help on this one as well. The most important thing, however, is that I'm doing this for an assignment of mine and there's one strict rule - **I MUST use a function** *called*

`char* encode(char* source, char const* alpha)`

Here's my piece of very primitive code:

```
    int len = strlen(source);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        switch (source[i])
        {
        case 'a': source[i] = alpha[0];
        case 'b': source[i] = alpha[1];
        case 'c': source[i] = alpha[2];
        ................................
        ................................
        ................................
        case 'y': source[i] = alpha[24];
        case 'z': source[i] = alpha[25];
        default: source[i] = source[i];
        }
    }
    cout << source << endl;
```

It basically should make an inputted string `source` of no more than 1000 symbols change all  of its lower-case symbols ('a' - 'z') to the corresponding symbol of the already inputted array (26 symbols in total for each lower-case letter... 'a' changes with a[0], 'b' with b[1], etc.).

There are several problems I have here:

1. My code won't work.. The output is always some weird symbols. How can i fix that?
2. How can I shorten it? Perhaps use a `for` statement instead of `switch`?
3. When it's working, how can I implement it to the function I mentioned in the beginning of my question (this is probably the most important one)?

Just for the record, here is my input code as well:

```
char source[1001];
cin.getline(source, 1001, '/n');

char alpha[27];
cin.getline(alpha, 27);
```

EDIT: I changed my code to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char source[1001];
    cin.getline(source, 1001, '/n');

    char alpha[27];
    cin.getline(alpha, 27);

    const int len = strlen(source);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if ('a' <= source[i] && source[i] <= 'z')
        {
            source[i] = alpha[source[i] - 'a'];
        }
    }
    cout << source << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Yet it became buggier. Now my console input never ends.... literally.. clicking Enter doesn't stop it.. nothing does.. When I changed my `cin.getline` for `source` to `10` it somehow ended though returned those weird symbols again - `╠╠╠╠`.

Comment: switch-case need `break;`

Comment: It's pretty unclear, what your problem is. Get to a prominent point (showing compiler errors, debugging results, unexpected outputs, etc.)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Good spot, within all that mess ;) ...

Comment: That code isn't so primitive as you think. The expansion from `'a'` to `'z'` has more uses than may first seem obvious, particular on systems where `'a'..'z'` is *not* contiguous (ex: EBCDIC). The self-assignment is useless, as are all but the last two assignments unless you're planning on including `break` stmts, or showing us the *real* code.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY - used `break;` on each case and the result is all the same - source: `This program is dumb.` alpha:
`qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm` output:
`T╠╠╠ ╠╠╠╠╠m╠ ╠╠ ╠╠╠`

Comment: Get rid of the last `getline()` parameter. You probably meant '\n` (notice the correct slash escape character) but you don't need it because newline is the default terminator.

Comment: @Blastfurnace - Oh, that was such a silly mistake... Thanks a lot! Do you have any idea about my third problem by the way? Or should I start another thread?

Comment: How come you're not using the function you MUST use in your edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cstring` instead of `string`:

```
#include <cstring>
```

And replace the `switch` with `if (source[i] >= 'a' && source[i] <= 'z') ...`

And this is your final code: https://eval.in/95037

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void encode(char *source, const char *alpha)
{
    int i, j;
    int len = strlen(source);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (source[i] >= 'a' && source[i] <= 'z') {
            j = source[i] - 'a';
            source[i] = alpha[j];
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char source[1001];
    char alpha[27];
    cin.getline(source, 1000);
    cin.getline(alpha, 27);
    encode(source, alpha);
    cout << source << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works wonders but how to make it as a `char*` (`char* encode(char* source, char const* alpha)`) instead of a `void`?

Comment: @user3213110 Why would you return a `char *` if you're modifying the original string?

Answer (score 3):

In a switch statement, when a case is matched the code executes all following cases unless you use a `break` at the end of each case. Your code is always falling through and hitting the default case.

Comment: used `break;` on each case and the result is all the same - source: `This program is dumb.` alpha:
`qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm` output:
`T╠╠╠ ╠╠╠╠╠m╠ ╠╠ ╠╠╠`

Answer (score 1):

Your switch statement executes every step because you never `break` or `return`.

Better:

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if('a' <= source[i] && source[i] <= 'z') {
        source[i] = alpha[source[i] - 'a'];
    }
}
```

Explanation:

`source[i] - 'a'` is `0` for `'a'`, `1` for `'b'`, etc. It generalizes the pattern you had.

Comment: Yes, you can do "character math" but you need to add the default action.  An else source[i] = source[i] will suffice.

Comment: @waTeim, `source[i] = source[i]` makes no sense.

Comment: @Paul Draper LoL.  .... need more coffee; yea, I was just cut-and-pasting, source[i] = source[i] is unnecessary.

Comment: @PaulDraper Thanks, this code looks decent. Though, would you mind checking my edit? I've described what I'm encountering with it. It still does not work. And do you have an idea how to rewrite it for the function I mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed you can just ignore the c-style string alpha and use the cctype function toupper(c).

```
#include <cctype>
for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(source); i++) {
    source[i] = toupper(source[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in c++:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
    wstring toLower(const wstring& str)
    {
        wstring temp = str;
        std::transform(temp.begin(), temp.end(), temp.begin(), ::towlower);
        return temp;
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    string toLower(const string& str)
    {
        string temp = str;
        std::transform(temp.begin(), temp.end(), temp.begin(), ::tolower);
        return temp;
    }
```