# How to write my own manipulator?

Tags: c++, manipulators

Let's suppose I want to write my own manipulator for input and output.

```
cin >> mymanip >> str;
```

or

```
cout << mymanip << str;
```

What I want that mymanip does is *toggle case* the caracters I read from input and assigns the result to one string.

So, if I type "QwErTy" I get "qWeRtY" in the string.

This is a very basic task with one function, but i want to learn more about manipulators.

Can someone give a clue?

Thank you.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358150/c-changing-lower-case-letters-in-a-string-function-again  and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313970/how-to-convert-stdstring-to-lower-case

Comment: @payamsbr, the links don't answer my question. What I want to know is how to create a manipulator. I just mentioned toggle string as an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way is a little tricky - but it can be done, you can add own manipulator for stream.

First, you need your toggle:

```
class toggle_t {};
constexpr toggle_t toggle;
```

Next - the version for `ostream` (the case for `istream` is very similar...):

After putting `toggle` to `ostream` - you need some special object:

```
struct toggled_ostream
{
    std::ostream& os;
};

inline toggled_ostream operator << (std::ostream& os, toggle_t)
{
    return { os };
}
```

Beware, that someone might put `toggle`in wrong place: `cout << toggle << 123` - so it should work for all other types as ordinary stream:

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator << (toggled_ostream tos, const T& v)
{
    return tos.os << v;
}
```

So - for char types (like `char`, `const char*`, `std::string`) write your toggle overloads. I am giving you version for `char` - it shouldn't be a problem to write version for "longer" types:

```
std::ostream& operator << (toggled_ostream tos, char v)
{
    char c = std::isupper(v) ? std::tolower(v)
                             : std::islower(v) ? std::toupper(v) : v;
    return tos.os << c;
}
```

Working [demo](http://ideone.com/w8Bc5i).

Comment: What is the use of the empty class => class toogle_t {};? and in my compiler I get an error with constexpr

Comment: 1) Maybe you have old compiler (not c++11) - use `const` instead.2) this is just tag class  3) Yes it works for next input - you must repeat it every time you want to print someting: `cout << toogle << c1 << toogle << c2` - some std manipulators work that - so this is nothing special about it...

Comment: As I wrote - I left to you to write  `std::ostream& operator << (toogled_ostream tos, const char* str)` and `std::ostream& operator << (toogled_ostream tos, const std::string& str)`

Answer (score 6):

All that a manipulator does is set the corresponding bits in the `std::ios_base` base class.

For example, the `std::setprecision()` manipulator simply [invokes std::ios_base::precision()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision), on the manipulated stream.

The implementation of `std::setprecision()` is almost readable, in gcc's headers (a rarity, for a C++ library template implementation):

```
 inline _Setprecision  setprecision(int __n)
     { return { __n }; }
```

`std::setprecision()` returns an internal `std::_Precision` object. Then, a simple template overload for the `>>` (and the `<<` operator, which is similar) operator, for the `std::_Precision` object, handles the rest of the magic:

```
 template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits>
    inline basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& 
    operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __is, _Setprecision __f)
    { 
      __is.precision(__f._M_n); 
      return __is; 
    }
```

In your case, there are no bits in the `std::ios_base` class that implement your desired input/output transformation. As such, a manipulator, per se, won't work here.

What you're trying to do requires a completely different, more complicated, approach:

1. A custom subclass of `std::[io]stream`, that uses a custom subclass of `std::streambuf`.
2. The `std::streambuf` subclass reads or writes from a chained stream, transforming the input or output as you've described.
3. Reading or writing from the custom subclass ends up reading or writing from the chained stream, transforming the data accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that. What you can do instead are manipulators that would take the string as argument, i.e.

```
std::cout << toggle(str);
std::cin  >> toggle(str);
```

A manipulator is only ever so-called syntactic sugar, i.e. it can do things more conveniently than otherwise. For example,

```
std::cout << std::setw(5) << x <<;
```

will do the same as

```
std::cout.width(5);
std::cout << x;
```

but is more convenient as it allows to be chained together with other `<<` operations.

Now, there is no formatting support of the thing you want (swap lower and upper case characters), and hence also no way to provide syntactic sugar for that.

However, if the manipulator can take your string as an argument, then of course, you can achieve what you want, implemented in the standard way of manipulator implementation. For example,

```
struct toggle_output
{ std::string const&str; }

inline toggle_output toggle(std::string const&str)
{ return {str}; }

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&out, toggle_output const&t)
{
  for(auto c:t.str)
    if     (std::islower(c)) out<<std::toupper(c);
    else if(std::isupper(c)) out<<std::tolower(c);
    else                     out<<c;
  return out;
}

struct toggle_input
{ std::string &str; }

inline toggle_input toggle(std::string&str)
{ return {str}; }

inline std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&in, toggle_input &t)
{
  in >> t.str;
  for(auto&c:t.str)
    if     (std::islower(c)) c=std::toupper(c);
    else if(std::isupper(c)) c=std::tolower(c);
  return in;
}
```

You may also need (to avoid confusion)

```
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&out, toggle_input const&t)
{ return out<<toggle_output(t.str); }
```

Answer (score 1):

As other answers explain, manipulators simply mimic existing `std::ios_base` functionality.

There's a simple solution to your problem, though I'm not sure if this can be called a manipulator:

```
struct toggle_in_helper
{
    std::string & res;
};

toggle_in_helper toggle (std::string & res)
{
    return {res};
}

std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & in, toggle_in_helper h)
{
    in >> h.res;
    for (auto & c : h.res)
        // toggle the case of 'c'
        ;
    return in;
}
```

That is, we create a helper class `toggle_in_helper` with overloaded `operator >>` which does the job.